# Communities Login URL to receive parameter

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-aura-components, community, lightning

For the communities, login component is available out of the box for the napili template. Login url will be of this format https://domain?param1=123&param2=123.
I want to retreive this param once the user is logged in.Is it possible to do?

Comment: Where is the user landing when this url is displayed? Is it on a page you control?

Comment: it then goes to /communitieslanding and then authenticator verification pops up and finally to community home page